# Modeling a fixed-depth tree in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, tree

I'm creating a SQL schema to represent a tree-like hierarchy, but I know for a fact that this tree will never be more than N-levels deep (where N is known at design of the application, most likely to be about 4 or 5).

If the depth of this tree is fixed, is it better to design the application by modeling each level of the tree as a table? Or would it be better to approach it with arbitrary depth in mind (e.g. adjacency lists or nested sets)?

I'm asking purely from a queryability perspective, e.g. reporting on various levels of the tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a single table with a well known hierarchical structure `(node_id, parent_id)` and an additional column `depth`. The column is theoretically redundant but can be very helpful in querying a specific tree level. Of course, such a structure makes it easy to walk the tree from top to bottom (or vice versa) using recursive queries.

```
create table a_tree(
    node_id int primary key, 
    parent_id int, 
    depth int
--  other columns
);
```

As a bonus, you can find many ready-to-use solutions for this type of tables on SO.

Comment: Are there any query _disadvantages_ to using a single table vs 5 tables, if I know that the tree depth will never grow in size?

Comment: You can still use single table and just join it 5 times instead of using 5 tables. From my own experience though, it may grow in the future and this approach let's you expand using WITH RECURSIVE query and saves you the disk space.

Comment: @J3Y - Conversely, I see a lot of inconvenience in using several tables instead of one. Think about, for example, defining views, functions, triggers etc. that should affect your data.